# EE2: Captcha if statement not working

Tags: ee2, solspace-freeform, captcha

I am trying to add a captcha to a [site](http://financialadvisorycorp.com/index.php/contact) that is running EE 2.6.1.  I am using solspace freeform 4.0.12 (the free version, not pro) and accessible captcha 2.3.  The code for the captcha is

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="margin-left:144;">
        {if captcha}
            <p>{captcha}<br /> <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" style="width:140px;" /></p>
        {/if}
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I remove the {if captcha} tags, the question/answer pair shows up, but it also allows the form to be submitted with an incorrect or missing answer.

I have also tested the page on multiple browsers to make sure that I'm not logged in.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Solspace respects the native captcha preferences you have setup in EE, whether member or not. You can override this by adding require_captcha="yes" as a parameter on your form tag.  Do you have that in place now?  Also, shouldn't it be {freeform:captcha} and not just {captcha} (namespacing it to freeform specifically)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For our FreeForm forms, we use the following code:

```
{if freeform:captcha}
      {freeform:captcha}<input type="text" name="captcha" style="width:140px;" />
{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize that freeform was required in the if tag.

Comment: 0
down vote
I have exact same problem, but using EE channel form with settings set to ON and correct folder permission. The bots are really picking a speed with spams.

Comment: I have exact same problem, but using EE channel form with settings set to ON and correct folder permission. The bots are really picking a speed with spams.